# GZIP compression enabled in Apache but not working with Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, gzip

I have enabled **gzip** compression in the Magento `.htaccess` file but online gzip test sites show that gzip is not enabled.

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
## enable apache served files compression
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#gzip

# Insert filter on all content
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
# Insert filter on selected content types only
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript font/woff

# Netscape 4.x has some problems...
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html

# Netscape 4.06-4.08 have some more problems
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip

# MSIE masquerades as Netscape, but it is fine
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

# Don't compress images
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary

# Make sure proxies don't deliver the wrong content
Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 6):

You are called in `.htaccess` is correct. if it is not work.

**1. Ensure that the module file is installed.**

This file is part of the core apache2 package which you should already have installed per the previously mentioned prerequisites. By default, it is found in `/usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_deflate.so`.

**2. Check if the module has been loaded.**

Open the module configuration file `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/deflate.load` , which is a symlink to `/etc/apache2/mods-available/deflate.load`, and ensure this line is present and not commented out:

```
`LoadModule deflate_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_deflate.so`
```

Hope it will helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

It might be you can't use the htaccess method. Here's an approach that worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24876371/compressing-js-css-files-where-mod-deflate-not-available/25960273#25960273.